# I don't understand why an Objective-C delegate function works and a Swift delegate function crash. Can you explain to me?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, casting, nsarray

I have a framework built in Objetive-C. That framework is to connect and interact with a Bluetooth device.

In the demo code, the Objetive-C delegate function looks like. The demo code was provided by the creator of the framework.

```c
-(void)babyScaleManagerScanDevices:(NSArray<ELBabyScaleDeviceModel *> *)babyScaleDevices{
    NSLog(@"babyScaleManagerScanDevices = %@",babyScaleDevices);
    ELBabyScaleDeviceModel *model = babyScaleDevices.firstObject;
}
```

I've included the framework in my swift project and imported the headers. I'm trying to obtain the same result by doing:

```swift
func babyScaleManagerScanDevices(_ babyScaleDevices: [ELBabyScaleDeviceModel]?) {
    guard let device = babyScaleDevices?.first else {
      print("Error unwrapping first device")
      return
    }
    print("Device: \(String(describing: device))")
  }
```

I get the following exception:

```
Thread 1: Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
Expected ELBabyScaleDeviceModel but found ELPeripheralModel

Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
Expected ELBabyScaleDeviceModel but found ELPeripheralModel: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1100.2.274.2/swift/stdlib/public/core/ArrayBuffer.swift, line 354
```

Inspecting  `babyScaleDevices` array show:

```
babyScaleDevices    [ELBabyScaleDeviceModel]?   1 value some
[0] ELPeripheralModel * 0x281cae100 0x0000000281cae100
```

This result is the same in the demo code in Objetive-C and my Swift project.

The class `ELBabyScaleDeviceModel.h` looks like:

```c
#import "ELPeripheralModel.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ELBabyScaleDeviceModel : ELPeripheralModel

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Can you explain me what is happening?

Comment: From error it seems that you should have `func babyScaleManagerScanDevices(_ babyScaleDevices: [ELPeripheralModel]?) {`. Maybe there is a bug inside a framework. Try to change it to this if your compiler will let you.

Comment: Change `func babyScaleManagerScanDevices(_ babyScaleDevices: [ELBabyScaleDeviceModel]?)` to `func babyScaleManagerScanDevices(_ babyScaleDevices: [ELPeripheralModel]?)`, but clearly there is a mistake in the framework. I hope there is a quick way to create a `ELBabyScaleDeviceModel` from a `ELPeripheralModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify Array to NSArray

Add this line to your code

```
let devices = babyScaleDevices as NSArray
```

You can try this

```
func babyScaleManagerScanDevices(_ babyScaleDevices: [ELBabyScaleDeviceModel]?) {
let devices = babyScaleDevices as NSArray
guard let device = devices.firstObject else {
    print("Error unwrapping first device")
    return
}
print("Device: \(String(describing: device))")
```

}

And after then check this -> [Array vs NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889705/in-swift-difference-between-array-vs-nsarray-vs-anyobject#:~:targetText=4%20Answers&targetText=Array%20is%20a%20struct%2C%20therefore,bridged%20to%20Array%20.&targetText=It%20will%20also%20work%20if,as%20with%20other%20reference%20types.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
func babyScaleManagerScanDevices(_ babyScaleDevices: [ELBabyScaleDeviceModel]?)
```

to

```
func babyScaleManagerScanDevices(_ babyScaleDevices: [Any]?)
```

and cast specific elements to `ELBabyScaleDeviceModel`, for example, in `for`.
It seems like the creator of this framework put ELPeripheralModel in the array instead of ELBabyScaleDeviceModel

Answer (score 0):

I think its just the way that the code is bridged to Swift.

Could you try to specify the type as `[ELPeripheralModel]` and then cast it?

```
func babyScaleManagerScanDevices(_ babyScaleDevices: [ELPeripheralModel]?) {

    guard let devices = devices = babyScaleDevices as? [ELBabyScaleDeviceModel], 
          let device = devices?.first else {
      print("Error unwrapping first device")
      return
    }
    print("Device: \(String(describing: device))")
}
```